# Avoid unwanted XML structure inside XML response

Tags: xml, http, xmlhttprequest, client-server

I'm developing an iPhone app, client uses HTTP POST to send messages to the server.
Server response with xml.

This is a messaging app, so users sends text messages to one another.

Now what happen if user send a text message that looks like a xml structure?
This could break the xml that the server sends to the client, how can I be sure this won't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the user defined message into a [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) section in your XML structure, this will prevent any parser from evaluating this part :

```
<message>
    <![CDATA[ my user content which won't be parsed ]]>
</message>
```

You won't have any problem this way, as long as the user payload doesn't contain the `]]>`, but you can easily [get around this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Nesting).